# How can I make find return non-0 if -exec command fails?

Tags: find

When I run the `find` command with an `-exec` subcommand that fails, `find` returns a `0` exit code:

```
$ find . -iname '*.txt' -exec ls foo \;
ls: foo: No such file or directory
ls: foo: No such file or directory
ls: foo: No such file or directory
ls: foo: No such file or directory
ls: foo: No such file or directory
ls: foo: No such file or directory
ls: foo: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
0
```

Is there any way to make `find` fail if any of its subcommands fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the limitation of find. 
Refer to the standard:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html

It will return 0 unless error happened while traversing directories.

Use xargs instead.

Comment: Can you please expand on what you mean by "use xargs instead"? An example would be appreciated.

Comment: find . -iname '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -n 1 -0 ls foo